# Unobtrusive Knockout Template Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I've been experimenting with an unobtrusive Knockout data-binding jQuery plugin.  Follow the link [here](http://joel.net/wordpress/index.php/2011/06/unobtrusive-data-binding-for-knockout-js/).

I cannot seem to figure out how to keep the "data-bind" attribute out of a template, though.  I can't decide whether or not it should even be done, either.  I just have a hunch.

**Example template:**

```
<script id="storeTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>
        <div class="storeTitle" data-bind="click: select">${storeTitle}</div>
    </li>
</script>
```

I'm thinking that it might be a good idea to pull `data-bind="click: select"` out of there.  Does anyone have an idea as to how to do that?  I've tried `$(".storeTitle").dataBind( { click: "select" } );`  A jQuery selector only selects objects that have already been created in the DOM, yet the elements we want to edit are not part of the DOM yet.  Also, I would like to avoid applying bindings more than once.

Comment: I just checked the code and I don't see any reason why the plugin won't work in the template. You need to do it the same way using `$(".storeTitle").dataBind( { click: "select" } );`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  I tried the line above before (just tried it again, too) and it didn't work for me.  I looked through the plugin too and it only selects objects that have already been created in the DOM, as jQuery normally does.  I'm going to update my question a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I just sort of answered my own question.  Considering that the elements in the template are actually sitting in the DOM (just in string form) I could just modify the string and add the data-bind="click: select".  Rather than doing string manipulation, a coworker suggested I just temporarily insert the template text as innerHTML to add it to the DOM, modify it using the plugin, insert the modified version back into the template as text and apply bindings.

Comment: Just make sure that you test it in IE :)  IE seems to be a little finicky about editing the text of an existing script element.  Otherwise, I was going to suggest something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/5dkMg/ where you load them into a jQuery object and don't actually insert them into the DOM.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer - Thanks a lot for this tip!  I just noticed that the code I made doesn't work in IE<9.

Comment: I found that IE<9 do not support modifying innerHTML of elements either.  I got around it by just deleting and recreating the elements.  Also, they remove double quotes from attributes in the innerHTML, which doesn't help if you want to modify it and create another element from it.  I had to play with regular expressions for a while to work around that one